# Is there any way to POST values while redirecting to an ASPX page from a Code Behind method

Tags: c#, asp.net, post

Is there any way to POST values while redirecting to an ASPX page from Code Behind, I can send it using a get like below

```
Response.Redirect("AdminRegisterTeacherEdit.aspx?messageID=" + messageID);
```

So, AdminRegisterTeacherEdit.aspx page retrieves the messageID, but it can be seen in the URL, I need to do it from a code behind method using POST, Please suggest me a way.

Comment: You can use `Session`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Session` instead, like this:

```
Session["YourIDValues"] = YourListOfIDValues;
```

Note: `Session` holds objects, so you can put whatever you want in `Session`.

To retrieve the value from `Session` you need to do this:

```
if(Session["YourIDValues"] != null)
{
    List<string> myListOfIDValues = Session["YourIDValues"] as List<string>;
}
```

Note: You must cast the object to the right type when retrieving the value from `Session` cache.